# Bounty was automatically awarded to an unhelpful answer

Tags: support, bounty

I had a bounty expire on an open question. Instead of refunding me the bounty, it was automatically awarded to an answer that did nothing to help me. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29175855/1256015). That does not seem right to me. This post presumed that I was ignorant about the topic, which I am not. He explained how to do something my software has been doing for a long time and then went on to explain that I probably wasn't right about what I thought the problem was.

I need the bounty to be extended so that I can continue to try and get an answer.

Why would the bounty be automatically awarded to an answer I have reviewed and not chosen?

Comment: [how does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: The system doesn't know that the answer didn't help you - as far as it is concerned, it is eligible because it has at least two upvotes. The fact that you didn't downvote the answer either, as there are no downvotes on the answer at all, doesn't really help matters.

Comment: Bounties are never refunded. That was stated **up front** when you created the bounty.

Comment: I didn't down vote out of an attempt to be courteous and avoid insulting someone who at least thought they were trying to help.

Comment: You seem to have no qualms about posting here calling it useless and insulting on meta though.

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger: but that's what voting is *for*. If the answer is not helpful, you downvote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right. I try to be very sparing with down votes, only using them when the answer is wrong or misleading to those who come behind. However, I will clearly have to be more protective of my bounties in the future.

Comment: @BoltClock - True enough. I held my tongue before, but now I'm rather upset at how the bounty went to the person who assumed I was ignorant. I didn't feel the need to speak to that until it turned out that that very person got my bounty for not only not helping me, but for condescending to me in the process. It's the bounty that pushed me over to speaking my mind.

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger i agree with you about the flawed bounty system, but not with your opinion about the answer. the answer provided a concrete code example to discuss. but the explanation seems to focus more on the image. maybe it's something you should bring up with the author of the library

Comment: @symbiont The library is an Apple library.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The bounty was automatically awarded, see the [Help Center on Bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) (emphasis mine):

> **If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.** If two or more eligible answers have the same score (i.e., their scores are tied), the oldest answer is awarded the bounty. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

While you failed to award the bounty, the answer met the criteria for an automatic award of half of the amount.

If you still need an answer, then you'll have to start another bounty on the question. However, the new bounty will be double your original bounty.

Comment: First, I have no idea why other people upvoted the answer. As stated in my op, the "answer" presumed I didn't know how to scan, which I do. It further asserted that I was wrong about the type of barcode I was trying to scan, I'm not as proven by the fact that hardware scanners to recognize it and by the fact that all US licenses are required to have a PDF417 barcode. So whatever the motives of those who did upvote, they were not helping me. I understand how bounties work and have used them successfully before, but this time I feel the automatic award has done harm.

Comment: @ChuckKrutsinger If the answer didn't solve your problem or failed to answer the question, then why not utilize your downvote?

Comment: Fair question. I generally only down vote answers that are just plain wrong. In this case, the person gave a useful answer to someone who did not know how to use the library in question, it just didn't answer my question. I already use that library and I already have a call just like the one shown. I'm very sparing with down votes. However, next time I put a bounty up, I will have to be more assertive with down votes because of this situation.

Comment: The quote in the answer states clearly HOW MUCH the bounty system is BROKEN by its own construction. Now add the @Martin Pieters comment https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288617/bounty-was-automatically-awarded-to-an-unhelpful-answer#comment168589_288617 "Bounties are never refunded" and see how much motivation a person has to give a bounty. I will NEVER give a bounty again!